# common overlap of N circles

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computer-science, computational-geometry

Having N circles represented by their radius and center coordinates , I wanted to know if there exists an algorithm for finding whether or not the point P exists such that P is inside all of the circles.

Comment: Not your final answer, but maybe this could help some: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Comment: O(N^3) will do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple O(n^3) method is to simply compute the points of intersection for every pair of circles and then for each intersection point test to see if it is in all of the circles.

There will be O(n^2) intersection points, and testing each of these takes O(n), so overall it is O(n^3).

I believe the only way there can be points inside all circles and not an intersection point is if the innermost circle is completely inside the other circles, so you should also test the centre of each circle.

Comment: Thank you .
I disagree on the last part .

Comment: Detecting if a circle is inside all other circles can be done in intersection points calculation.

Comment: One speedup: If there's no point common to all circles, it's likely that there is some pair of circles that don't intersect.  So for many "No"-instances, you can get a correct "No" answer in just O(n^2), and the 2-circle intersection test is very quick: is (r1+r2)^2 < (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2?  (This doesn't catch *all* "No"-instances though: e.g. it's possible to arrange 3 circles so that any pair of them has some slight overlap, but no point is in the common intersection of all 3.  Thus the full O(n^3) is still needed in the worst case.)

Comment: Yep actually I did the exact same thing .

Comment: i think this does not work (or needs another step).   Consider two intersecting circles and a third that fully encompasses the first two (no intersections). The large circles center need not be in the intersection region of the first two for that region to be common all three.

Comment: @george: I think your example *does* work: those two intersecting innermost circles produce 2 intersection points, and these points will be found to be inside all 3 circles, giving a correct "Yes" answer.  (For this example, circle centre points aren't needed.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker you are right, i misread the last part. of course only the smallest circle can be inside the rest

Answer (score 3):

If you could calculate intersections sequentially then you can get `O(N^2)` algorithm.

Each circles intersection is a convex figure similar to a polygon, but with arc sides. After you intersect `n` first circles you'll get the intersection area with not more than `O(n)` sides. So in order to calculate its intersection with the next (`n+1`-th) circle you'll need `O(n)` work. Going over all `N` circles you'll need the `O(N^2)` work total.

The advantage of this algorithm is also its earlier termination with answer `no` - if you get an empty intersection on step `n` it won't become nonempty in following steps.

A disadvantage - a necessity to deal with "arced" polygons.

Comment: That's a nice approach . Thanks.

Comment: be sure for each intersection check to consider cases of added circle being entirely inside or entirely outside the arc-side-polygon.

Comment: This might still be a good approach, especially if you order the circles nicely, but your claim that intersecting any n circles produces a figure with at most n "arc sides" is wrong. Suppose you have two large circles that only intersect a little bit, producing a tall, narrow "lens-shaped" intersection. Now a third, smaller circle centered at the centre of the lens and having diameter slightly larger than the width of the lens at its widest point will clip the lens at both the top and bottom, introducing *two* new "arc edges". In general I think 1 more circle can create n new edges.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - I agree, my claim looks weak without proof. I'll try to find it

Comment: @HEKTO: Do you mean you'll look for a proof of your claim that there can be at most n "sides" after n circles have been intersected?  Because I just showed you a counterexample...

Comment: @j_random_hacker - please look at my answer, there are `O(n)` sides

Comment: Apologies, poor reading comprehension on my part! I think your claim has a good chance of being true, but I have no clue how to prove it.  Starting from a regular n-gon (with "arc sides", though these can be made arbitrarily close to lines by increasing the radius of the generating circles), intersecting with 1 more circle can clip off all n corners, adding n new sides.  It would suffice to show that, for any set of n circles with n-sided intersection, there can be at most a constant number of such "heavy" (Omega(n)-new-side-producing) steps as further circles are intersected.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - good idea, thanks! Yes, a regular polygon with `n` sides can be intersected with a circle, giving `2*n` intersection points. But - it looks like this process can't be continued. I mean - a *next* circle, which will double a number of intersection points again, looks impossible to me.

Comment: You're welcome, but my "It would suffice..." claim was (also!) wrong -- it could be that successive intersections produce o(n) new sides each, but that cumulatively there are still too many.  E.g. the sum of the first n harmonic numbers (1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ...) converges to n log n, which is not O(n); so if, say, there exists some set of n circles with n-sided intersection such that n more intersections can be performed (for a final total of 2n circles), with intersection number (n+k) multiplying the side count by (1+1/k), then there can be Omega(n log n) sides.  Dunno if this is plausible...

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if O(N) algorithm is possible:

1) Find out the circle with smallest radius. Denote it as Cs.
2) Check if Cs is completely enclosed by all other circles. If yes, any point within Cs is the solution. If no, ignore those circles that completely enclose Cs. This will reduce the number of circles to M, where M <= N. 
3) Check if any circle intersects Cs. If no circle intersects Cs, there is no solution. If yes, find if any of the intersection points is within all the rest of (M-1) circles. If yes, the intersection point is the solution. If no again, then no solution.

All the above steps are O(N) for computation, so the overall computation should be O(N) as well.

Comment: +1 for first discarding everything fully containing the smallest circle. I think that takes care of the issue I noted in @PeterdeRivaz answer.  However in worst case you may still need to check all O(N^2) circle-circle intersections. Consider three circles of radius 2 at ({1,0},{0,0},{-1,0}} to see why that's the case. (make the center one slightly smaller if you want )

Comment: @george: You are right. In step (3), we should find ALL the intersection points between Cs and other circles. This should handle your "three overlapping circles" example and also keep the algorithm O(N).

Comment: On a secoond thought, even computing all the intersection points will not help. Guess we have to resort to O(N^2) algorithm after all.